# How to find index in AngularJS through directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have tried to get index like this

this is my html

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="findindex($index)"></div>
```

this is controller

```
 $sceop.findinedx=function(index)
{
    alert(index);
}
```

here i am able to get index value.but i want to get index value through directive

this is my html

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in items" my-directive></div>
```

this is my directive

```
   app.directive('myDirective',function()
   {
        return function(scope, elem, attrs,$index) 
        {
              elem.bind('click', function($index)
              {
                   alert($index);
              });
        });
   };
```

here i am not able to get index..so how to get index value in directive?

Comment: You should really consider using an isolated scope for something like this.  Having the directive rely on `$index` is bad practice.  See my answer for elaboration.

Answer (score 5):

Each of the `ngRepeat` iterations has a different scope. Use `scope` to access the respective indices:

```
elem.bind('click', function($index){
    alert(scope.$index);
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/WAT4d/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for your answer...but i am not able to get parent index...i have tried like this scope.$parent.$index but this is not working ....

Comment: @silvesterprabu You would be able to access `$parent.$index` only if you have nested `ng-repeat`s.

Comment: @silvesterprabu I have added a fiddle. May be you can update your question to include HTML with both the repeats.

Answer (score 5):

I have an app that looks like this, and it works.  No need to bind to `$parent`.  Everything is in your scope because the directive hasn't defined anything other than the default scope:

http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/yFbuc

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
});

App.directive('myDirective',function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attrs,$index) {
    elem.html(scope.item)

    elem.bind('click', function($index) {
      alert(scope.$index);
    });
  };
});
```

**BUT, YOU SHOULD RECONSIDER**

Writing directives this way is bad practice.  One of the key concepts of directives is that they should encapsulate behavior.  You are breaking encapsulation by having the directive peek into the `$index` like that.  It requires that it be inside a repeater, which also breaks encapsulation.

Instead, consider using an isolated scope and passing the values in via parameters instead.

The HTML would look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" my-directive="item" index="$index"></div>
```

And then you define the directive a bit differently, using an isolated scope:

```
App.directive('myDirective',function() {
  return {
    scope: {
     index: '=',
     item: '=myDirective'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs,$index) {
      elem.html(scope.item)

      elem.bind('click', function($index) {
        alert(scope.index);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

[Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/BrianGenisio/pen/yFbuc)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use in the directive attribute "let ind=index"

For example :

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let i of items; let ind= index">
        {{i}}
        <span (click)="removeItem()" class="remove_link">X</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```